# DFA worst case states

Tags: automata

Suppose an NFA which accepts language of the form
L(N) = {w| w has 1 in n$^t$$^h$ from last symbol.}
Then the corresponding DFA would have 2$^n$ states(worst case of subset construction).
If we are to prove that equivalent DFA has 2$^n$ states, then we take 2 string as
a$_1$a$_2$a$_3$.....a$_n$ and b$_1$b$_2$b$_3$....b$_n$ and consider two cases:

1) a$_i$ $\neq$ b$_1$, i=1.
   this case is clear to me....

2) a$_i$ $\neq$ b$_i$ , i>1.
   I am having trouble in understanding this case.
   If both a$_i$ and b$_i$ has same value for n$^t$$^h$ symbol from last, then automaton would be in accepted state after reading a$_n$ and b$_n$. So why do we need to remember every possible string sequence for this case.

Thanx!

Comment: The language of words that have a $1$ in the $n$-th position can be recognized by a DFA with $n+2$ states.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It's n-th from last, so for equivalent DFA it must have 2$^n$ states.

Comment: Ah, okay, but then you need to change the description: ‘last $n$-th’ does not mean ‘$n$-th from last’.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry mistake is mine.

Comment: No problem! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is that you don't know until you get to the end *which* symbol is the $n$-th from last.  To understand what is going on, you need to think about how the automaton should process strings of more than $n$ symbols, rather than of exactly $n$ symbols as you seem to be doing.

As a hint to hopefully help you come up with a formal proof:  Think about what information you need to remember as you are processing a string.  You need to remember every $1$ you see, and how far 'back' in the string you saw it, in case it turns out to have been in the $n$th-from-last position.  Except you can forget any information from before the most recent $n$ characters of the string, since any $1$ read before then can't possibly be the $n$th-from-last symbol.

Comment: I understand that from subset construction, it'll have 2$^n$ states, how to prove it taking string w, |w| > n.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question (if it is a question).

Comment: I am asking how to prove(formally not intuitively) it that for string greater than n, requires 2$^n$ states if n-th from last symbol is 1.

Comment: Do you understand it intuitively, for a start?  (In your original question, you didn't seem to believe it was true, so I guess at least at that point you hadn't understood it intuitively.)

Comment: your answer was useful so did i mark it. It gave me insight to case length greater than n.

Comment: I added what may be a hint or may have already been clear to you.  I don't have time to write any more now, probably for the rest of today (UK time).

Comment: I'll work it out later... , by the way sorry for extended conversation, i did not see you edited the answer and added hint there. thanx!